# Sync-ing a basic IMAP client w/ server

Tags: imap

I am writing a simple IMAP client that will be able to sync w/ any Google email account.  I don't want to have to read the ENTIRE set of message headers on the server every time I sync in order to be assured that I do not miss something.  I would prefer to not ever have to do that, and to rely on some field that ensures total order.  For example, I would prefer to rely on Google extended Message ID field or even just on Receieved-Date and have my logic be: "keep reading backwards until you hit something you have previously read".  But alas, it does not seem to be that simple.

What is the preferred way to do sync such that it is both efficient (in terms of time + bandwidth) and guaranteed (i.e., no missed messages)?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10111058/1305501 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9967266/1305501

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.  Does anyone know if this approach is implemented by any Java/Google IMAP client libs?